# Service Territory object access to Partner User

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I have the following scenario:

1. My user has the Partner Community license and the profile is a custom one , called Agent
2. When I want to debug a flow as my partener user it says that it doesn't have access to the Service Territory object.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tedF.png)

In order to solve the root cause I have done the following:

- I have revised the Agent profile visibility for Service Territory object and everything is fine as it has read access
- Taking into account that the Service Territory object is part of Field Service I have assigned the user the permission set license field service license which should basically give read access to the Service Territory object

**
Unfortunately, none of this worked. Would you have any suggestion on which I could solve the problem? Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

You assigned license, ok. but have you assigned a permission set (there may be one built in coming with FSL or create a custom one and give Read permission via it?)

When all else fails you probably can move this part of flow's logic to Apex [InvocableAction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) and use SOQL without the security checks the developer is supposed to normally do ("without sharing", not using "describes", not using "WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED"). Shady but well...

Comment: Thank you for your guidance! Indeed, I was missing two important permission sets: Field Service Community Dispatcher License  
 && Field Service Community Dispatcher Permissions